# GL Context destruction

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I create the GL Rendering Context successfully (I checked return values of all WinApi functions). When I am trying to destroy the context using the following piece of code it fails:

```
    bool success = ::wglMakeCurrent ( 0, 0 ); // false
    success = ::wglDeleteContext ( glRenderingContext_ ); // false
```

All described above happens in one thread. What is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried using the [Win32 API GetLastError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and its ilk to see what went wrong?

Comment: Did you already destroy the window which held the device and rendering contexts?  You mention THESE statements happen in one thread--is that the same thread that owns your window and initialized the contexts in the first place?

Comment: Yes, I destroyed the window before the context destruction. Thx. Now, it is ok. You can write this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you destroy the window that held the device and rendering contexts before making this call?  You should shut down your rendering context before you destroy your window.